# How to separate int values from a mixed string (search terms)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a short way to separate int values from a string like "john 15 doe 1988"

I'm building a full-text search query and cannot add int field to the catalog and also cannot use a view because query contains XML fields.

I must build a SQL where I can query like

```
ID IN (15, 1988)
```

or

```
ID = 15 OR ID = 1988
```

My current code is separating each word by space character.

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Pos INT
DECLARE @Len INT
DECLARE @Word NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SearchTerm = 'john 15 doe 1988'
SET @SearchTerm = RTRIM(LTRIM(@SearchTerm))

SET @Pos = 0
SET @Len = 0

IF LEN(@SearchTerm) > 0
BEGIN
    --Add space as last char if not space
    IF(CHARINDEX(' ', @SearchTerm, LEN(@SearchTerm) - 1) = 0)
        SET @SearchTerm = @SearchTerm + ' '

    WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @SearchTerm, @Pos+1)>0
    BEGIN
        SET @Len = CHARINDEX(' ', @SearchTerm, @Pos+1) - @Pos
        SET @Word = CAST(SUBSTRING(@SearchTerm, @Pos, @Len) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

        PRINT @Word

        SET @SQL = @SQL + 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, ' + @Word + ') OR'

        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(' ', @SearchTerm, @Pos+@Len) + 1
    END
END
```

Note the query should support SQL server 2008 and I cannot use TRY_PARSE()

Comment: So, you need to check if any of given set of numbers is contained in string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ISNUMERIC to determine if the expression is a valid numeric type.

[ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0

```
IF ISNUMERIC(@Word) = 1 SET @SQLIDs = @SQLIDs + @Word + ', '
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question. I was sitting bored. I just tried my own way. Just a try . posting here

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @letter VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @length INT
DECLARE @preSpace INT = 0

CREATE TABLE #Final (value INT)

SET @pos = 1
SET @output = ''
SET @str = 'john 15 doe 1988 testing 6 768 i955 99 my pretty 74j4'

SELECT @length = len(@str)

WHILE (@pos <= @length)
BEGIN
    SELECT @letter = SUBSTRING(@str, @pos, 1)

    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            WHERE @letter IN (
                    '1'
                    ,'2'
                    ,'3'
                    ,'4'
                    ,'5'
                    ,'6'
                    ,'7'
                    ,'8'
                    ,'9'
                    ,'0'
                    ,' '
                    )
            )
    BEGIN
        IF (
                @letter = CHAR(32)
                AND @output <> ''
                AND @preSpace = 0
                )
        BEGIN
            SET @preSpace = 1

            INSERT INTO #Final
            VALUES (@output)

            SET @output = ''
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @preSpace = 0
            SET @output = @output + '' + CAST(@letter AS VARCHAR) + ''
        END
    END

    SET @pos = @pos + 1
END

IF (@output <> '')
    INSERT INTO #Final
    VALUES (@output)

SET @output = ''

SELECT *
FROM #Final

DROP TABLE #Final
```

Comment: I guess it has some bug, it shouldn't return 744

Comment: Ok ok . so you don't need thess two 'i955,74j4'?

Comment: Nope. This is for a global search and we are only interested in space separated expressions